# Java Mission Control displaying "Flightrecorder is not supported for non hotspot jvms"

Tags: java, jmc

When I was trying to profile my local Java application by running *Java Mission Control* (`jmc`), I wasn't able to connect to the application. It displayed *'Flightrecorder is not supported for non  hotspot JVMs'* in the description of all JVM processes displayed in the left pane.
My environment: *Windows 7, Java 8u25*

Because I wasn't able to find solution for this problem anywhere on the net, I want to share the solution that I luckily discovered for other people (and my future self) who might run into the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here I am posting the solution and observations that lead to the solution.

When I (by coincidence) tried to run `jvisualvm` it displayed error "Local Java applications cannot be monitored". On http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html in section titled *"Local Applications Cannot Be Monitored (Error Dialog On Startup)"* I found that on Windows system there could be problem with one exact folder name if the account name contains capitalized letters.

Solution was to alter the name of folder `%TMP%\hsperfdata_username` in a way that the capitalization corresponds with the my username (there was *'e'* instead of *'E'* in the folder name). 
After this change, both `jmc` and `jvisualvm` started to work again.

*Note*: you need to kill all currently running Java applications before changing the name of the folder.

Comment: This is something maybe we (as in the JMC dev team) should put somewhere in our help/FAQ.

Did you look anywhere in our documentation or on our forum for an answer to this?, as a hint to us about where we should put it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for documenting your solution here. Worked for me. You have to compare the folder name with "echo %username%"

Comment: Thanks so much this and Gabor Liptak comment saved my life